# How is Acknowledgement generated in I2C ,in either master or slave?

Tags: vhdl

I want to know how are acknowledgement(ack) and not-acknowledgement(nack) generated from slave or master when transmitting data to slave, or receiving from slave and what is the optimal method to detect it in ,specifically, vhdl and verilog.

Comment: Hello, welcome on SO. SO is about software programming. Your question is not a software question. You could try, for instance, [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a software programming question (it would be if you had a piece of code to share about which you need help).

Comment: @RenaudPacalet, how is this not a programming question? Not the best posed question of all times, I'll admit, but still a software question.

Comment: @Max I think it would be a programming question if it was about a piece of shown VHDL or Verilog code to be fixed. As it is, at best, it is an electrical engineering question about the I2C protocol (see the title: "_How is acknowledgement generated in I2C, in either master or slave?_"). At worst it is opinion-based ("_what is the optimal method to ..._"). I may be wrong, of course.

Comment: @Ddraig77 ACK and NACK are clock synchronous data bits. So just sample them with a rising clock edge. If you are on an FPGA the SDA need to be a tristate-buffer. When sending data count the bits and reverse SDA in/out value after 8 bits to sample the ACK/NACK. Then continue sending data (if ACK). Usually your FPGA clk will be a few magnitudes faster than a I2C clk, so you have enough time to switch SDA in/out and so on between I2C clocks.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet, I'm pretty sure ES will say "Thats a software question, go ask on SO" ;)

Comment: @Max Maybe, maybe not. But if you look at your own answering comment you'll see that there is no programming at all in it. Anyway, feel free to answer it if you wish. If I am the only one to think it is not a programming question it will not be closed and it will stay there.

Comment: [UM10204I2C-bus specification and user manual, Rev. 7.0 — 1 October 2021](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10204.pdf) (I2C was originally implemented in very simple HW).

Comment: *...what is the optimal method to detect it in ,specifically, vhdl and verilog* isn't a specific programming question. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Verilog is not programming language, only hardware description language, so we should delete whole community.